# Can not pass data to ng-bootstrap with @input

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a component with a list of all users, and when we click on `edit` or `add new` I open same modal box with a form for edit or for add new user. In case I want to edit user I need to show user data in form in modal box. My modal box is in another component, and I need to pass data to modal.

In my `user.component` I get data for selected user and I set it to

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AddComponent);

this.userService.getUserDetail(username).subscribe((response: UserModel) => {
    this.user = response;
    modalRef.componentInstance.user = this.user;
  });
```

And in `modal box component` I set

```
export class AddComponent {
      addNewUserForm: FormGroup;
      @Input() user;

constructor (...){
      console.log(this.user) //get undefined
  }
}
```

I also try set `console.log(this.user)` in `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit` but always get `undefined`

Thank you for help...

Comment: All looks good with the code. If the `response` has some value, it should come to the `AddComponent`. Can you create a stackblitz for the issue ?

Comment: @arter porperty is not available in life cycle hooks or constructor but you can use it in some method after opening the modal check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtihfs) open modal and click log property button

Comment: @jitender yes, when I make function and call this after modal I initialized I get data... but is there any way to "onLoad" or "onInit" or something else get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer
if I put `const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AddComponent);` inside `subscribe` I get data with `ngOnInit(){console.log(this.user)}`

```
this.userService.getUserDetail(username).subscribe((response: UserModel) => {
this.user = response;

const modalRef = this.modalService.open(AddComponent); //i put this here
modalRef.componentInstance.user = this.user;
});
```

and in `add.component.ts`

```
export class AddComponent implements OnInit{
  addNewUserForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() user;

ngOnInit(){
  console.log(this.user);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngOnInit` instead of `constructor`

```
ngOnInit() {
      console.log("hihi", this.name)
   }
```

Hi, I've made a working [Stackbligz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-modal-content-elren4)

Comment: this is not working, already try this... like @jitebder write above "property is not available in life cycle hooks or constructor but you can use it in some method after opening the modal".

Comment: As per your requirement I made a stackbigz app where you find the 'hihi world' in the console. Pardon me If I'm wrong

Comment: yes, you are right... but when i use ngOnInit i get undefined... Becuase, I get data from API and modal is opened before I get data....

Comment: @Arter then you should open modal after you get api response

Comment: @varman I upvote for your answer but that is not the correct answer. In my main question, I write that I already try with `ngOnInit` but not working. The solution is like I add an answer, change `const modalRef...` to another position... I can not mark my answer like correct... `You can accept your own answer in 2 day`... But tm thank you for suggestion

Comment: @Arter you can also use the `ngOnChange()` along with `@Input user`. The function gets triggered whenever an input property changes